# В обьекте Response, что приходит от сервера на Node JS, отсутствуют заголовки

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, cors, express-sessions

Написал сервер на Node и клиентскую часть на Vue (не до конца). Приложения работают на одном домене, но на разных портах.
Вот код на клиентской части, который посылает запрос.

```js
[AUTH_IN] ({ commit, state }) {
      fetch('http://localhost:9135/login',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(state.authData),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cookie': docCookies.hasItem('sid') ? docCookies.getItem('sid') : ''
          },
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials: 'same-origin'
        }
      ).then(res => {
        console.log(res.headers)
        if (res.headers.has('Set-Cookie')) {
          docCookies.setItem(res.headers.get('sid'))
          commit(LOG_IN)
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        commit(SET_ERROR, { error })
      })
    }
```

Запрос нормально обрабатывается сервером и отдает ответ с куками и заголовками:

```
[Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
[Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
{ 'x-dns-prefetch-control': [ 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control', 'off' ],
 'x-frame-options': [ 'X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN' ],
 'strict-transport-security':
  [ 'Strict-Transport-Security',
    'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains' ],
 'x-download-options': [ 'X-Download-Options', 'noopen' ],
 'x-content-type-options': [ 'X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff' ],
 'x-xss-protection': [ 'X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block' ],
 'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080' ],
 vary: [ 'Vary', 'Origin' ],
 'access-control-expose-headers': [ 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Set-Cookie' ],
 'set-cookie':
  [ 'Set-Cookie',
    'sid=zF3Uh7qNmTz_lN3KAfyJB3CcDeMW8OI1; Max-Age=3599; Path=/ Expires=Thu, 13 Sep 2018 20:43:48 GMT; HttpOnly' ] }
```

Вот код на сервере, что обрабатывает запрос:

```js
export function authorizeUser (req, res) {
  const { username, password } = req.body

  if (uname === username && pass === password) {
    store.set(req.sessionID, req.session, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
      } else {
        res.cookie('sid', req.sessionID, req.session.cookie)
        console.log(res)
        res.sendStatus(200)
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401)
  }
}
```

Но на клиенте в ответе с сервера свойство headers об'екта Response есть - пустое. Примечательно то, что Postman все заголовки ответа отлично видит и обрабатывает куки. Что нужно сделать, чтобы клиентский код видел заголовки ответа сервера?

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name Set-Cookie нельзя увидеть в скриптах.

Comment: Ну и вообще там много разных условий на то, что доступно в ответе

Comment: @AlexeyTen, так как тогда на клиенте получить куки? Или они самостоятельно запишутся в document.cookie?

Comment: Судя по тому, что написано здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Куки - куки клиент никак не обрабатывает и они будут передаватся на сервер при каждом запросе, так как их путь я не обозначал (используется по-умолчанию: "/"). Также на куках стоит флаг httpOnly.

Comment: При условии, что они вообще выставятся. Вообще идея с разными портами дурацкая, с точки зрения браузера это разные сайты со всеми вытекающими ограничениями

Comment: @AlexeyTen, точно... Я понимал, что будет сложно связать два разных приложения, но и не знал про "клиент-серверную архитектуру". Благодаря вашему ответу, я смог найти правильный вопрос, на который Google дал что-то внятное) Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Да, действительно `headers`, ответа пустой. Мне самому интересно почему так происходит. Могу только предложить использовать методы объекта `headers` `.get() .has() .forEach()` , показывают не все, но хоть что-то.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.headers.has('cache-control')) {
            console.log(response.headers.get('cache-control'))
        }
    });

// public, max-age=14400

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.headers.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
    }));

// public, max-age=14400
// application/json; charset=utf-8
// Fri, 14 Sep 2018 00:35:50 GMT
// no-cache
```

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. На часом деле из всех заголовков мне нужен только ‘Set-Cookie’, чтобы сохранить ID сессии на клиенте. А именно этого заголовка и нету( Я уже подумываю отказаться от куков в пользу sessionStorage и ручную реализацию обмена этого ID.